Argument of type ChatOpenAI<ChatOpenAICallOptions>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'BaseLanguageModel<any, BaseLanguageModelCallOptions>
Referring to official docs of langchain, I replicated code exactly same from it.
    const datasource = new DataSource({
        type: "sqlite",
        database: "../../../../Chinook.db",
    });
    const db = await SqlDatabase.fromDataSourceParams({
        appDataSource: datasource,
    });
    const llm = new ChatOpenAI({ model: "gpt-3.5-turbo", temperature: 0 });
    const sqlToolKit = new SqlToolkit(db, llm); // <- second parameter is incompatible

getting error for last line where i am passing db and llm to SqlToolkit:
Argument of type 'ChatOpenAI<ChatOpenAICallOptions>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'BaseLanguageModel<any, BaseLanguageModeCallOptions>'.
Type 'ChatOpenAI<ChatOpenAICallOptions> is missing the following properties of type  'BaseLanguageModel<any, BaseLanguageModeCallOptions>': CallOptions, _patchConfig

I have tried from docs only and not able to get solution for it.
